# Does the Google App Engine (Python) offer a command-line console interface?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm hoping it offers something like the [Rails console](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console), where I can interact with models directly in a local instance.

I know about the [development console](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_The_Development_Console), but I'd prefer to work from a terminal rather than a web interface.

Comment: If you want your hands dirty, use IaaS instead of PaaS - get GCE instead of GAE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like the [Remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi)

To use it towards the local dev server (which the development console does a better job of):

```
$ python2 ~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/remote_api_shell.py -s localhost:8080
Email: test@example.com
Password: 
App Engine remote_api shell
Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 24 2014, 18:26:21) 
[GCC 4.9.1 20140903 (prerelease)]
The db, ndb, users, urlfetch, and memcache modules are imported.
dev~{appid}>
```

Comment: That looks sorta like what I had in mind. But I'd prefer to interact with a local instance (i.e., the development server). I don't want to touch production data.

Comment: A little extra help for others who may be interested in this: You must first start your local dev server. When you do that, it will start the API server: `INFO     2014-12-12 15:53:41,661 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at: http://localhost:35905`. Use that port number with the `remote_api_shell.py` call above.